# JSP Expression Language get parameter

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am trying to get a `String` parameter `"username"` from the `request` with **Expression Language**.
I've done some research, but couldn't find a way to do so, I would like something similar to `${pageContext.request.parameter.username}`

How get a specific request parameter, using only expression language?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get an attribute from `session` use `${myattr}`.

To get a parameter from `request` use `${param.myparam}`.

Comment: Thank you. But can you please link me the source for this information?

Comment: You question is actually about object scope in JSP. For your reference, check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Answer (score 7):

The syntax to get the attributes from session would be,

```
${sessionScope[name]}
```

And for the request attributes , you can use

```
${param[name]}
```

For more info,

- [Examples of EL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)
- [Java ee tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/#wp71043)

Comment: For request attributes you should use quotes to wrap the parameter's name. ${param['name']}