# Servlets, JPA, JSP - Servlet don't work correctly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jpa

I don't know why my servlet doesn't work. My code bellow:

userOrdersServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/userOrders")
public class userOrdersServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        int userId = (int) session.getAttribute("userId");
        UserDAO daoUser = (UserDAO) request.getAttribute("userDao");
        User user = daoUser.getUser(userId);
        List<Books> booksOrderedByUser = user.getBooks();
        request.setAttribute("booksOrderedByUser", booksOrderedByUser);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userOrders.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

userDAO.java

```
public User getUser(int id) {
        this.em.clear();
        return this.em.find(User.class, id);
    }
```

userOrders.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Library Online</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <%@include  file="templateTop.jsp" %>
<div class="main"><table border="1">
    <h2>Your orders</h2>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Author</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Category</td>
                <td>Year</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="booksOrdered" items="${booksOrderedByUser}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${booksOrdered.title}</td>
                    <td>${booksOrdered.author}</td>
                    <td>${booksOrdered.description}</td>
                    <td>${booksOrdered.category}</td>
                    <td>${booksOrdered.year}</td>
                    </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </table>
    </div>
                    </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <br>


</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>RegisterLoginJPA</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
<filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>filters.sessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/loginSuccess.jsp</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So I used code from `userOrdersServlet.java`and display data using foreach loop and `System.out.println()` in another servlet and it works correctly. But when I go to `userOrders.jsp` it doesn't show any data, What I did wrong?

Comment: Post your web.xml  and the rest of your userOrder.jsp please. What error are you facing also?

Comment: I didn't notice any error, every other servlet works well, i put simple redirect to doGet method in this servlet and still don't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to display on userOrders.jsp books ordered by user using expresion language but when i go to this page it's only shows me blank table, but  as i wrote i display i'm using another servlet to display results via `System.out.println()` it works pretty well

Comment: Did you add the jstl jars to your project(WEB-INF/lib)?

Comment: Yes, I use jstl in antoher jsp and it works very well

Comment: is this line returning the values you're expecting:

List<Books> booksOrderedByUser = user.getBooks();

Comment: Yes, it returning correct values

Comment: I go to userOrders.jsp by `<a href="userOrders.jsp">Orders</a>`

Comment: I think maybe this: items="${booksOrderedByUser}"> should be items="${param.booksOrderedByUser}">

Comment: Wrap this around your loop in your jsp to see if the list is empty or not:

<c:if test="${not empty booksOrderedByUser}">}">
    ...
</c:if>

Comment: What happens if you change the link to <a href="userOrders">Orders</a> i.e. map the link to the Servlet which then forwards to the JSP.

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks, that fix my problem, but i using doGet method how can I change it to doPost?

Comment: Just override the doGet() method in the servlet and call doPost(request, response) from within.

Answer (score 0):

To access a request parameter in a JSP you need to precede the parameter name with "param." So

```
<c:forEach var="booksOrdered" items="${booksOrderedByUser}">
```

should be:

```
<c:forEach var="booksOrdered" items="${param.booksOrderedByUser}">
```

see: [JSP Expression Language get parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747831/jsp-expression-language-get-parameter)