# JSON getParameter returns null while ${} does not

Tags: json, jsp

I am writing a simple webserver for my unity game. The problem is if I do `${list}`, it displays the JSON string but if I do it in scriptlet it returns null value.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/distance.do")
public ModelAndView distance(CommandMap commandMap) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("distanceProc");
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = sampleService.distance(commandMap.getMap());

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        obj.put("city", list.get(i));
    }

    String jsonString = obj.toString();

    mv.addObject("list", jsonString);

    return mv;
}
```

distanceProc.jsp

```
${list}
```

`${list}` displays

```
{"city":{"cityName":"*****","distance":0,"latitude":*****,"cityId":*,"longitude":*****}}
```

while

```
<%
String data = request.getParameter("list");
System.out.println("Received Data: " + data);
%>
```

returns null. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `list` is http request parameter?

What will the result be on

```
<%
String data = request.getAttribute("list");
System.out.println("Received Data: " + data);
%>
```

EL expression `${list}` will give you the value of `list` attribute [in one of the page, request, session, and application scopes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html). If `list` is really http request parameter and you would like to access it via EL than use `${param.list}`.

In case it solved the problem:

- [Difference between getAttribute() and getParameter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter)
- [JSP Expression Language get parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747831/jsp-expression-language-get-parameter)